# Access data from AppDelegate in ViewController.

Tags: ios, objective-c, count, parse-platform

I'm a beginner programmer and new to this site and I tried looking for a solution before asking but had trouble wording it so sorry if this has been asked before.

I'm using Parse and essentially my main goal right now is to just display the number of users in the app in a label.

In my AppDelegate.m

```
PFQuery *userCountQuery = [PFUser query];
[userCountQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int userCount, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
        NSLog(@"There are %d users", userCount);
    } else {
        // The request failed
    }
}];
```

That code gets the proper number in my console and now I'm only challenged with getting this variable into the view controller for use with the label. Is there a simple way to do it or is my method of accomplishing this flawed from the start?

Comment: Why don't you just take your whole query and put it in the view controller. No need to run it from app delegate.

Comment: Try setting the count in a @property `userCount` in `AppDelegate` and access it in  `ViewController` by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].userCount`

Comment: @Logan Wow sorry I guess I was following the guide too strictly. This seemed to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that currently you have a method in AppDelegate with you snippet, just like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate {
...

- (void)countUser;
}
```

Then you can change that method to:

```
- (void)countUserWithSuccessfulBlock:(void (^)(int))successfulBlock
{
    PFQuery *userCountQuery = [PFUser query];
    [userCountQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int userCount, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The count request succeeded. Log the count
            NSLog(@"There are %d users", userCount);
            successfulBlock(userCount);
        } else {
            // The request failed
        }
    }];
}
```

Then from your ViewController:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication shareApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate countUserWithSuccessfulBlock:^(int result) {
    //Display to your label;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you create create a getter/setter in your app delegate but it's not the right way to develop. I meant you should have more layer in your APP such as manager, to handle theses kind of datas

Here you can try first to see it works

My structure will allow you later to just move the code from appDelegate to any other class/place since you might use getter/setter soon during your learning ;)

**myAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
}
```

**----------**

**myAppDelegate.m**

```
@interface myAppDelegate()

@end

@implementation myAppDelegate

- (int)getProperNumber
{
    return properNumber;
}
```

**----------**

**ViewController.m**

```
mAppDelegate * appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int count = [appDelegate getProperNumber];
```

Cheers.